# Laravel unique registration token

Tags: php, laravel, token

I try to make registration only for people they have a token (a randomly generated key) but I have the Problem that I cant compare my token input with the database.

I tried this:

```
$token = Tokens::findOrFail($data['register_token']);

                if($token) {

                    return User::create([
                        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
                        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
                        'register_token' => $data['register_token'], 
                        'email' => $data['email'],
                        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                        'role' => 'student',
                    ]);

                }
                else {

                    return redirect('/register')->with('unkown_token', 'This Token does not exist!');

                }
```

I always get an 404 Not found Error. I generated tokens with 
`$string = str_random(40);`

Comment: What is your Tokens table structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FindorFail works on primary key.

For custom column, add `protected $primaryKey='custom_column_name'` in the model. But if you don't want to do so then try regular conditional query given below.

```
$token = Tokens::where('register_token',$data['register_token'])->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me but I still get an 404 error because he cant find localhost:8000/register but on an `<a href="/register"></a>` in the view he can find the route? With a correct token i can register now, but without I still get an 404 error

Comment: `firstOrFail` search for result in table and if not found then throws exception.  So in order to redirect `/register` route if token not found, just use first() instead of firstOrFail() which returns null if result is not found then your else condition will work redirecting the /register url.

Answer (score 0):

If `register_token` is not the primary key of `tokens` table, getting `404` is logical. Remember in `findOrFail($id)`, `$id` is the `primary key` of that table. If `register_token` is not your `primary key` and you want to query based on `register_token` then your query should be

```
$token = Tokens::where('register_token', $data['register_token'])->firstOrFail();
```